# How to load one page from another on select of option from drop down?

Tags: php, hyperlink, html

I have a drop down list on click of the option I want to redirect to another page in same tab according to type selected.

I want to redirect to, like if user selects ssgt then need to go to ssgt.php if selects tsgt then tsgt.php and like that for msgt.

Is it can be done with link inside? I tried but did not work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>MCQ Questions</title>     
</head>
<body>
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Select rank : 
      <select name="type" id="type" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 
         <option value="1">SSgt</option> 
         <option value="2">TSgt</option> 
         <option value="3">MSgt</option> 
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <?php
         if(isset($_POST['type'])) {
            if(strcmp($_POST['type'],"1") == 0) {
            }
         }
      ?>    
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help.. Thank you.

EDIT:

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MCQ Questions</title>

</head>
<body>


<form method="post" action="mcq.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['type']))
    {

        if(strcmp($_POST['type'],"1") == 0)
        {
            header("Location: ssgt.php");
        }
        elseif(strcmp($_POST['type'],"2" == 0))
        {
            header("Location: tsgt.php");
        }
        elseif(strcmp($_POST['type'],"3" == 0))
        {
            header("Location: msgt.php");
        }
    }

    ?>

    <h2>Lets add a question, Select a rank for which you want to add a question.</h2>
<br><br>
Select rank : 

<select name="type" id="type"  onchange="this.form.submit()">


    <option value="1">SSgt</option>
<option value="2">TSgt</option> 
<option value="3">MSgt</option> 
</select>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried this way so for ssgt, and tsgt respective pages are getting open but for msgt the page of tsgt.php is getting open.

Comment: Use `header("Location: some_page.php")` on top of your script (before any HTML output). More here: http://php.net/manual/bg/function.header.php

Comment: it wont be a single same page I want to redirect to, like if user selects ssgt then need to go to ssgt.php if selects tsgt then tsgt.php and like that for msgt.@mitkosoft

Comment: Simple switch-case can do that - see below.

Comment: If I get that right then you want to redirect the moment a selection has been made, _not_ until the form has been submitted. For that you need client side logic, so javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put simple `switch/case` on very top of your script:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['type'])) {
        switch($_POST['type']) {
            case 1:
                header("Location: ssgt.php");
                break;
            case 2:
                header("Location: tsgt.php");
                break;
            case 3:
                header("Location: msgt.php");
                break;
        }
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>MCQ Questions</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select rank :
            <select name="type" id="type" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value="">Select rank...</option>
                <option value="1">SSgt</option>
                <option value="2">TSgt</option>
                <option value="3">MSgt</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code must be placed on very top (before HTML tag). Check updated answer.

Comment: yes working,, but for ssgt if it is selected by default when the page is loaded if we click on ssgt option from drop down it dose not work.

Comment: :) Yes, because you don't have an empty option in order to tell to user to pick an option - see latest update.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like below;

```
if(isset($_POST['type']))
{
    if(strcmp($_POST['type'],"1") == 0)
    {
       header("Location: ssgt.php")
    } else {
       header("Location: msgt.php")
    }

}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MCQ Questions</title>

</head>
<body>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Select rank : 

<select name="type" id="type" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 

    <option value="1">SSgt</option> 
<option value="2">TSgt</option> 
<option value="3">MSgt</option> 
</select>

<br><br>



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can add so many condition as you want as per your drop down list.

Thanks

Comment: you can print $_POST['type'] and check what value is you are getting after form submit, secondly you can also compare the values like this  if($_POST['type']== 1) and  if($_POST['type']== 2)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, in line
`<option value="1">SSgt</option>`
the "value" attribute will be submitted. You shuould submit name of the page you want to redirect. So change all your `options` as
 `<option value="SSgt">SSgt</option>`

your final code will be

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
    $location = strtolower($_POST['type']) . '.php'; // Will convert SSgt to ssgt.php
    header("Location: " . $location);
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>MCQ Questions</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select rank : 
            <select name="type" id="type" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 
                <option value="SSgt">SSgt</option> 
                <option value="TSgt">TSgt</option> 
                <option value="MSgt">MSgt</option> 
            </select>
            <br><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```